# Why is there a maximum hardware limit of 2048 pixels with multiple monitors

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, display

[image]

As seen in the image, trying to have the 2 displays side by side creates this problem. There is a 2048x2048 box limit. My question is, what creates this limit and why. What would happen if I try with 3 displays or with 2 huge ones. Even better, what would happened if I tried a single monitor at resolutions of 2560x1600 or 2560x2048.

I see that it says "Hardware Limit". Does it mean the limit is made by the video card, all video cards, a specific monitor/tv or all monitors/tvs. This has always crossed my mind many times and since we are almost finished with 2011 (Happy Holidays and Happy New Years to all) I wanted to kick this doubt out of my mind so if someone else asks I can tell them.

Comment: According to wikipedia the Max resolution for anything is 2560x2048, so technically you are trying to use a resolution bigger than the limit.

Comment: @UriHerrera but I checked and for example WQHD that is 2560 for example. Of course am exaggerating but just to make a point. What I really want to know is who is creating the limit.

Comment: The title suggested you want to plug in at least 2049 monitors. That made me lol.

Comment: Who? well the Manufacturers, since the Monitors we use are not for any special uses (medical use and air traffic control, support resolutions up to 4096×2160[From Wikipedia]) we don't **need** no more than what the current limit is.

Comment: You can check more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution

Comment: @UriHerrera, "max resolution for anything" is overly broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a limit on the open source driver you are using for your video card. I had attempted the same at work and got the same error (although with a different max resolution size listed). Installing the proprietary drivers (ATI) I was able to get the screens side by side.

At home I have nVidia and already had the proprietary drivers installed when I added a second screen. Here is a screenshot of the display settings via the nVidia settings manager.

[image: nVidia settings]

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem because of an Idea by Jester. In this case it is a hardware limit for this Intel card, although there are newer Intel video cards that limit this to 4096x4096. More info here: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2

But basically, depending on the video card is the limit of rendering/buffering of the screen.

Another source of information is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution about the resolution multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

If this may be to some help to you, i know it has been caused by [an intel driver that had failure in the pas](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=849462)